# how to hide display pictures smoothly ? html

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make simple image slider. i've succeed to do it using javascript and html. have a look at the code bellow.

i have put all the codes just to make every thing clear. the problem is just with **showItemAtIndex** function . once it's change the display property for the images the webpage scroll suddenly to the top of the image. very weird.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbdabp0t/)

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
<script>

/*
   @param carousel_id: the tag id which hold the carousel componenets.
   carousel container structure should be as the boostrap container structure.
 */
var ImageSlider = function(carousel_id)
{

  var parent = this;
  this.selected_item_index = 0;//image index which currently visible. by default first image is the selected one
  this.carousel_container = document.getElementById(carousel_id);//container which contain the main slider
  this.carousel_items  = this.carousel_container.getElementsByClassName("carousel-inner")[0].getElementsByClassName("item");
     this.carousel_indicators = this.carousel_container.getElementsByClassName("carousel-indicators")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");

  //listen to next events click, when user wanto to see the previous image
  this.carousel_container.getElementsByClassName("right carousel-control")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){

       var new_item_index = parent.selected_item_index + 1;
       new_item_index = new_item_index % parent.carousel_items.length;
       showItemAtIndex(new_item_index);


  });


  //listen to prev events click. when user need to show the next image
  this.carousel_container.getElementsByClassName("left carousel-control")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){

    var new_item_index = parent.selected_item_index - 1;
       if (new_item_index < 0) {
        new_item_index = new_item_index + parent.carousel_items.length;
    }
       showItemAtIndex(new_item_index);


  });

     /*this function will show the the item at the given itemIndex */
  var showItemAtIndex = function(itemIndex){

      /*
         TODO:
             step1 : update carousel images
             step2 : update carousel-indicators
             step3: update this.selected_item_index
      
       */

       /* now we need to show the new selected item */
    var carousel_height = parent.carousel_container.height;
    var new_selected_item = parent.carousel_items[itemIndex];
    new_selected_item.style.display = "inline-block";
       
       //step1
   /* first thing we need to hide the current selected items */
   var current_carousel_selected_item = parent.carousel_items[parent.selected_item_index];
   current_carousel_selected_item.style.display = "none";
   //Animate(current_carousel_selected_item,0);

  

     

      //step2
   /* remove active from all elements */
   var carousel_indicators_length = parent.carousel_indicators.length;
   for(var i = 0 ; i < carousel_indicators_length ; i++ ){
    var monoCarouselIndicator = parent.carousel_indicators[i];
    monoCarouselIndicator.className = "";
   }

   /* add class active to indicator at selected element */
   var selectedIndicatorElement = parent.carousel_indicators[itemIndex];
   selectedIndicatorElement.className = "active";

   //step3
   parent.selected_item_index = itemIndex; 
   
   
     }


     /* we should hide all items but not selected one(selected one = at first index) */
     var carousel_item_length = this.carousel_items.length;
     for(var i = 1; i < carousel_item_length ; i++){
         var monoItem = this.carousel_items[i];
        // monoItem.style.height = "0px";
         monoItem.style.display = "none";
     }
    

}


</script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
 crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
body {
 background: #ececee;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>
 <!-- header section -->
 <div class="container header" style="height:300px;" >
  
 </div>

 <!-- carousel section -->


 <div class="container carosel_section" id="carosel_section">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>

   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active" style="height: 100%;">
     <img style="height: 100%;" class="img-responsive"
      src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738A6E00000578-3504412-image-a-6_1458654517341.jpg">
     
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 100%;">
     <img style="height: 100%;" class="img-responsive"
      src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="item" style="height: 100%;">
     <img style="height: 100%;" class="img-responsive"
      src="http://eskipaper.com/images/images-4.jpg">
    </div>
   </div>

   <!-- Left and right controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button"
    data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"
    aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel"
    role="button" data-slide="next"> <span
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- load image slider -->
 <script>
 new ImageSlider("myCarousel");
 </script>
 
 <!-- bottom section section -->
 <div class="container header" style="height:300px;" >
  
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the HTML of the left and right controls. Remove `href="#myCarousel"` and it will work properly. Then it will look like this:

```html
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
```

And here's a working demo:

```js
var ImageSlider = function(carousel_id) {
    var parent = this;
    
    // image index which currently visible. by default first image is the selected one
    var selected_item_index = 0;
    
    // container which contain the main slider
    var carousel_container = document.getElementById(carousel_id);
    var carousel_items = carousel_container
      .getElementsByClassName("carousel-inner")[0]
      .getElementsByClassName("item");
    var carousel_indicators = carousel_container
      .getElementsByClassName("carousel-indicators")[0]
      .getElementsByTagName("li");
 
    //listen to next events click, when user wanto to see the previous image
    carousel_container
      .getElementsByClassName("right carousel-control")[0]
      .addEventListener("click", function() {
        var new_item_index = selected_item_index + 1;
        new_item_index = new_item_index % carousel_items.length;
        showItemAtIndex(new_item_index);
    });
 
    //listen to prev events click. when user need to show the next image
    carousel_container
      .getElementsByClassName("left carousel-control")[0]
      .addEventListener("click", function() {
        var new_item_index = selected_item_index - 1;
        if (new_item_index < 0) {
            new_item_index = new_item_index + carousel_items.length;
        }
        showItemAtIndex(new_item_index);
    });
 
    // this function will show the the item at the given itemIndex
    var showItemAtIndex = function(itemIndex) {
        /* TODO:
         step1: update carousel images
            step2: update carousel-indicators
            step3: update this.selected_item_index
     */
  
        // now we need to show the new selected item
        var carousel_height = carousel_container.height;
        var new_selected_item = carousel_items[itemIndex];
        new_selected_item.style.display = "block";
  
        // step1
        // first thing we need to hide the current selected items
        var current_carousel_selected_item = carousel_items[selected_item_index];
        current_carousel_selected_item.style.display = "none";
        //Animate(current_carousel_selected_item,0);
  
        // step2
        // remove active from all elements
        var carousel_indicators_length = carousel_indicators.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < carousel_indicators_length; i++) {
            var monoCarouselIndicator = carousel_indicators[i];
            monoCarouselIndicator.className = "";
        }
  
        // add class active to indicator at selected element
        var selectedIndicatorElement = carousel_indicators[itemIndex];
        selectedIndicatorElement.className = "active";
  
        // step3
        selected_item_index = itemIndex;
    }
 
 
    // we should hide all items but not selected one (selected one = at first index)
    var carousel_item_length = carousel_items.length;
    for (var i = 1; i < carousel_item_length; i++) {
        var monoItem = carousel_items[i];
        // monoItem.style.height = "0px";
        monoItem.style.display = "none";
    }
}

new ImageSlider("myCarousel");
```

```css
body {
    background: #ececee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- header section -->
<div class="container header" style="height:300px;"></div>

<!-- carousel section -->
<div class="container carosel_section" id="carosel_section">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active" style="height: 100%;">
                <img style="height: 100%;" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738A6E00000578-3504412-image-a-6_1458654517341.jpg">
            </div>
            
            <div class="item" style="height: 100%;">
                <img style="height: 100%;" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="item" style="height: 100%;">
                <img style="height: 100%;" class="img-responsive"
                    src="http://eskipaper.com/images/images-4.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```